# How to construct multiple inner joins through relations in QueryDSL - Referring to intermediate tables

Tags: querydsl

I'm having trouble constructing queries which combining inner joins in `QueryDSL` where the tables are not in a

```
A --> B --> C
```

relation, but rather

```
A --> B <-- C
```

Here is my SQL query

```
select s.* from sales s
inner join branch b on b.id = s.branch_id
inner join manager m on m.branch_id = b.id and m.name = 'Alice';
```

(extracted from my example here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r5uvEsivyAhrP6KSpwJxBA/1 )

So for my QueryDSL equivalent I have:

```
query.innerJoin(QSales.branch, QBranch)
     .innerJoin( ??? )
```

I can't work out how to construct the next inner join.

Everything I've tried gives me exceptions like `Path expected for join!`

Hypothetically, if it were One-to-One I could just  chain like this ...

```
query.innerJoin(QSales.branch, QBranch)
     .innerJoin( QBranch.manager, QManager ).on(QManager.name.eq('Alice'));
```

But I don't have that relation.

I can't find the right construct in QueryDSL to model this, but I'm assuming it will be possible?

Comment: I think I'm missing the problem. Why wouldn't the normal pattern work like this? query()
.select()
.from(sales)
.innerJoin(branch).on(branch.id.eq(sales.id))
.innerJoin(manager).on(manager.branchId.eq(branch.id).and(manager.name.eq("Alice"))); (obviously select what you want in the select call)

Comment: `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join!`

Answer (score 0):

*Typically having concocted some samples, I found the right combination.*

**This solution replies on having a `ManyToOne` mapping between B & many Cs**

```
query.innerJoin(QSales.branch, QBranch)
     .innerJoin( QBranch.managers, QManager )
       .on(QManager.name.eq('Alice'));
```

with `managers` listed in branches QueryDSL knows what to do and produces the kind of SQL that works for me.

I still don't know how to solve this is managers is not mapped.